# encoding is not working for certain characters

Tags: java, encoding

I have few characters in my document like , ,  and . I am tried UTF-8 and UTF-16 as encoding, when I read the inputstream. Then I do some processing, like show the text on browse, write the text in output file. It all looks good and I see the same character.
Though, I am also calculating the number of characters in each word and when I count the number of characters for these, it comes out to be 2. I looked and internally, java string corresponding to these words are like ð¿, which is clearly 2 characters.

I thought using the UTF-8 encoding, should just give me exact character but it is giving me something weird. Any idea what I might be missing

Comment: It's very hard to diagnose what's wrong from a fairly vague description. Please provide a [mcve] - ideally using a byte array hard-coded in the example as input, so that it's completely self-contained.

Comment: You better make clear how you are "counting the characters" and for which "words" it is incorrect according to you. I doubt whether it has anything to do with UTF-8 or UTF-16, though, but more about the internal representation of Unicode characters in Java

Comment: When you use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), characters may be represented by a variable number of bytes. Some characters will be 1 byte, other characters will be encoded with 2 or more bytes. The number of **characters** is not the same as the number of **bytes**. Maybe you are counting the number of bytes and you expect that that's the same as the number of characters. If you get things like "ð¿" then you are making a character encoding or decoding mistake; you are, for example, interpreting UTF-8 as if it is some other character encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confused.

Strings do not *have* an encoding.

Bytes (so, `byte[]`) has an encoding. Strings do not.

Whenever you convert `byte[]` to string (and standard input is bytes, not strings, as is standard output. Files are bytes. Data travelling over a network, unless encapsulated in some character-oriented protocol, are bytes too), an encoding is applied.

Whenever you convert a string to bytes, an encoding is applied.

Thus, once you have a java.lang.String object, there are only two options:

1. The string is mangled gobbledygook because you had some bytes in e.g. ISO-8859-1 encoding, but you turned that into a string using `new String(theBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Note that `new String(theBytes)` is **banned** code and always buggy, don't ever call that method (that uses 'platform default encoding', which is a funny way of saying 'never what you want'). The fix is to create the right string. For example:

```
String x = "é";
System.out.println(x.length());
byte[] data = x.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String y = new String(data, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
System.out.println(y.length());
System.out.println(y);

> 1
> 2
> Ã©
```

See? This process has turned the data into meaningless garbage and the size of y is now just broken. There is no fixing this, other than by avoiding applying the wrong encoding.

Alternatively,

2. You have characters from one of the higher unicode planes.

Turns out that java was created in a time of transition, and java uses the so-called surrogate pair encoding internally. That means that all characters whose unicode number is very high (I believe, above 32767), are **actually represented by 2 chars, not 1**. These 2 chars go together and are called a surrogate pair.

The solution is to use the codepoint based methods that string has:

```
String simple = "é";
System.out.println(simple.length());
System.out.println(simple.codePointCount(0, simple.length()));
> 1
> 1

String complex = "";
System.out.println(complex.length());
System.out.println(complex.codePointCount(0, complex.length()));
> 2
> 1
```

`.length()` returns the number of 'unicode char units', which counts a unicode codepoint represented by a surrogate pair as **2 units**. The `codePointCount` method counts them as 1 unicode codepoint.

> I have few characters in my document like , ,  and

Thus if one of those characters has a high enough codepoint that it takes a surrogate pair to represent it, voila. This explains it - use `codePointCount` and not `length` (note that the performance characteristic of `codePointCount` is O(n) - it takes longer for long strings, as java has to iterate through the entire thing to find surrogate pairs and adjust the count accordingly).